# Is it possible to have the value of the jQuery UI slider on the slider button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

My client has asked me to code the below UI, the value of the slider is on the actual slider button.
http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/9043/sliderb.jpg

Can anybody point me in the direction of least resistance? and would it be possible to do with the jQuery UI slider or am I going to have to look elsewhere?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    create: function () {
        /* Set the handle text to min value */
        $(this).find("a.ui-slider-handle").text($(this).slider("option", "min"));
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find("a.ui-slider-handle").text(ui.value);
    }
});
```

With some CSS to spruce it up, you should definitely be able to accomplish that:

```
a.ui-slider-handle { text-decoration: none; }
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/T5Y7k/1/

Comment: Thank you so much it worked great, also I have another quick question. How do you do specific snap to values on the slider? the client doesn't want intervals of say 10 for example he wants 10,20,40,75,100,200. thanks again

Comment: @user827570: That's actually a pretty good question It might be better to ask a new question that asks that `:)`

Comment: @user827570: Actually, I would check out this question on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967372/jquery-slider-how-to-make-step-size-change

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jquery you could get the value of the slider, and then using CSS to put that value on the element of the slider.

Jquery allows you to change the default's UI css styling, so you could use the ID of that element to change it as you see fit.

There are widget-specific classes referenced within the *jquery.ui.slider.css* stylesheet that can be modified.
Check http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range, check the Theming tab on that link too.