# How to set the Step of a jquerymobile slider dynamically based on slider value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, slider

I have a jquery mobile slider :

```
<input type="range" name="slider" data-track-theme="c" 
        data-highlight="true" id="slider-step1" step="10000" 
        value="10000" min="10000" max="9000000" />
```

and I have to set the step value dynamically like this:
Up to 200.000 steps of 10.000, up to 500.000 steps of 25.000, up to 1.000.000 steps of 50.000, up to 2.000.000 steps of 200.000, up to 9.000.000 steps of 500.000.

I tried a lot of things and nothing.
Please help!

Comment: Interesting question but I'm not sure its possible.

Comment: I tried something on Change event and it does not work because I have to change the step before slider changes... What event should I use, or any other ideea?

Comment: Duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967372/jquery-slider-how-to-make-step-size-change

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, because jQueryUI != jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible!!
Try this solution with your value or variable:

```
$("#slider-step").attr("min", 4);
$("#slider-step").attr("max", 40);
$("#slider-step").attr("step", 4); 
$("#slider-step").val(4);
$('#slider-step').slider('refresh');
```

It works for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
$('#slider-step1').change(function(){
    currentValue = $(this).val();
    if(currentValue > 200000){
        $(this).attr('step','25000');
    }
    if(currentValue > 500000){
        $(this).attr('step','50000');
    }
    // and on and on 
});
```

I'm sure you will have to refine this to work as you want it to but this is the basic idea.

Comment: i tried this, the result you can see here: http://admin.realmediastore.ro/test.htm, so it not working correctly because it sets the step after slider changed, I think... any idea?

Comment: I did a lot of work, it;s not about that, I think I need to use another event then Change, because I need to set the next step before changing the slider value... you know what I mean?