# HTML range only defined values

Tags: html, range

Is there a way to define a set of values in a HTML range tag, which are the only ones that can be chosen ?

In my example, I want a slider `min = 0 max = 100` with the values `0, 30, 60, 100`.
Other values are not accepted and the slider jumps to the nearest value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a user input?

If it is, why not just present those values in a Select Tag?

Also this might be useful [JQuery Slider, how to make "step" size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967372/jquery-slider-how-to-make-step-size-change)